# How to change preview Image while dragging item

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I have a collection view with one big cell at (0,0) and the rest is smaller. I want to use drag & drop to reorder the cells.

I want the preview image to adjust to the cellsize I am hovering over. So over cell (0,0) it should be bigger than over the rest of the cells.

But I cannot find a way to change the preview image size once the dragging is in progress.

When I start dragging I use the following method to generate the dragItem

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, itemsForBeginning session: UIDragSession, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UIDragItem] {

    let object = photos[indexPath.item].image
    let item = NSItemProvider(object: object)
    dragItem = UIDragItem(itemProvider: item)
    return [dragItem]
}
```

I tried to play around with this function, as it gives me the current indexPath where I am dragging over. But ends up in a jitter-effect and cells don't rearrange anymore. I guess it's because this method is called a lot of times during the dragging process. What could be the solution?

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, dropSessionDidUpdate session: UIDropSession, withDestinationIndexPath destinationIndexPath: IndexPath?) -> UICollectionViewDropProposal {
if destinationIndexPath?.row == 0 {
  for item in session.items {
    item.previewProvider = {
      let test = UITextView.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200))
      return UIDragPreview(view: test)
    }

  }
} else {
  for item in session.items {
    item.previewProvider = {
      self.test = UITextView.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
      return UIDragPreview(view: test)
    }
  }
}
return UICollectionViewDropProposal(operation: .move, intent: .insertAtDestinationIndexPath)
}
```

Comment: Did you find any answer ?

Answer (score 1):

You should create your preview item in itemsForBeginning() when you create your item

```
dragItem.previewProvider = { () -> UIDragPreview? in
    var dragPreview: UIDragPreview?
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: "yourImage")
    imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100.0, height: 100.0) // You can change the size here
    dragPreview = UIDragPreview(view: imageView)
    return dragPreview
}
```